# res.redirect from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I'm trying to do a redirect after an ajax `put` request.  I plan on using pure JS client side for validation.

Client:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    login = () => {
        var username = $("[name='username']").val()
        var password = $("[name='password']").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "put",
            url: '/login',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
            // success: function(response) {
            //  console.log('Success:')
            //  console.log(response.user)

            //  Cookies.set('username', response.user.username)
            //  Cookies.set('first_name', response.user.first_name)
            //  Cookies.set('last_name', response.user.last_name)
            //  Cookies.set('email', response.user.email)

            //  window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/'
            // },
            // error: function(error) {
            //  console.log("Error:")
            //  console.log(error)
            // }
        })
    }

    logout = () => {
        console.log("Log out clicked.")
        Cookies.remove('username')
        Cookies.remove('first_name')
        Cookies.remove('last_name')
        Cookies.remove('email')
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/logout'
    }
})
```

Server:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('main')
});

router.put('/login', function(req, res) {
    // Password is not encrypted here
    console.log('req.body')
    console.log(req.body)

    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
        // Password is encrypted here
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('user')
        console.log(user)

        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result) {
            if (result) {
                var token = jwt.encode(user, JWT_SECRET)
                // return res.status(200).send({ user: user, token: token })
                return res.redirect('/')
            } else {
                return res.status(401).send({error: "Something is wrong."})
            }
        })
    })
})
```

I can't get `main.hbs` to render after a successful login.  My commented code works, but I'm trying to do my redirect server side rather than client side because I'm told that it's better for security.

Comment: your commented code is the correct way to work. there is no loss of security here. your redirect is communicated to user either way. server side redirect is deadend for an ajax request as the instruction is not for the browser but some javascript handler.

Comment: Thanks!  That's really good to know.  My commented code made sense to me, and I wanted to go that direction, but I was worried about security for the user.  If I'm able to use JavaScript on the client (before submitting the request to the server), I'll be able to do custom validations, rather than be limited to HTML5 form validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do is possible. An AJAX request is meant just to pass data back and forth. What happens now is that you need to script client side behavior on your end. This means the AJAX request will pass a 302 and other data that comes along for the ride to the callback on JS. No client side behavior can be altered from the server. It is up to you to do something with the AJAX returned values. If 500, throw an error message, 200 do something etc.

The only way you can get a server redirect to work is by traditional HTML form submission.

Comment: Ok, so I think I did that in my commented code, where I did a redirect with `window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/'` in the client.  For a login system, is it better to just use a traditional HTML for submission so that the redirect happens server side?

Comment: As with all things, it depends. If you are doing a pure single page application, then using the client side thing. However, judging from your code, you are not. Basic server side redirects would be better suited here in my opinion.

If you log into GMail or whatever, they are doing server side redirects as well. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something else I wanted to ask: in order to do a server-side redirect as you mentioned, I think I'd need to bypass client-side JS (which is how my code above currently works).  If I want to do custom validation using JS in the client (beyond what's available with HTML5 form validation), is that possible?

Comment: Why not? You can always attach a form submit listener or listeners to the controls you want and do whatever that's possible within JS.

Answer (score 11):

You should know when to use `href` and `replace` functionalities.

`window.location.replace(...)` will best way to represent an HTTP redirect.

**Reason**

When compared to `window.location.href`, `window.location.replace(...)` is better to use in a HTTP redirect scenario because `replace()` avoids keeping the originating page in the session history, this helps users to avoid get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco.

**Summary**

If you want to illustrate clicking on a link, use  `location.href`

If you want to illustrate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`

**Sample**

```
//  an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://example.com");

//  clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

**Update**

The server cannot do a redirect from an ajax request. In the end ajax involves the client (browser).

If you want, you can send the instruction of a redirection through the server side call, but it will be end up again on client side, in the callback. 
You can do that by returning an object from the server which contains the url you want to redirect to. Then use javascript to change the document's location property. Like Below:

Server Side Code

```
if (result) {
    var token = jwt.encode(user, JWT_SECRET)
    return res.status(200).send({result: 'redirect', url:'/'})
} else {
    return res.status(401).send({error: "Something is wrong."})
}
```

And then in Client Side Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "put",
  url: '/login',
  data: {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.result == 'redirect') {
      //redirecting to main page from here.
      window.location.replace(response.url);
    }

  }
});
```

Apart from this your commented code is the correct way to do this. Just like one of the comments in you question "server side redirect is deadend for an ajax request as the instruction is not for the browser but some javascript handler."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  Question: is one method better than the other for security?  Based on your explanation, I would guess `location.replace` is the way to go.

Comment: @Farid yes that's right use `location.replace` wherever u want a redirection

Comment: @Farid If the answer is useful and correct you could mark it as right answer!

Comment: What about security?  Is `location.replace` a secure method to use?

Comment: Isn't this going off tangent? He is asking for a server side redirecting of his page, not client side code. What you say is correct but his server side code won't allow window location changes, no?

Comment: @BenjaminWong 1) The server cannot do a redirect from an ajax request. 
2) In the end ajax involves the client (browser). 
3) If you want to redirect you can do it, but it is going to have to be done on client side, in the callback.