# Unable to redirect from POST Request with Express and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm making an app with Node.js, Express, and EJS, which should redirect you to a different page (e.g. from localhost:3000/ to localhost:3000/about) upon pressing a button. The post request is being received by the server since 'post request' is being logged to the server-side console, but I am not getting redirected, with no error message or anything.

server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.listen(3000)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => { //works as intended
    res.render('home')
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => { 
   res.redirect(307, 'https://google.com') //nothing happens, google.com as an example
   console.log('post request') //logged on server console
})
```

client:

```
button = document.getElementById('button')
text = document.querySelector('textarea')
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            data: text.value
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this question already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971141/res-redirect-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetch()` function you are calling in your client app is a function that lets you get information from a node.js API. However, it doesn't let you redirect to another page.

If you want to be redirected, you can use an html `<a>` element to point to the URL of your Express server, where you can be redirected to another page.

Server code:

```js
app.get('/redirect-me', (req, res) => {
   res.redirect(307, 'https://google.com') //nothing happens, google.com as an example
   res.render('home')
})
```

Client code (html):

```js
<a href="/redirect-me">Click here and you will be redirected to Google</a>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to send the data received from the post request to the page I want to redirect to?

Comment: I'm doing it on EJS so I have to load the documents from the client-side using res.render(...) to also send data, so I can't do it from the client-side